# Unity - My Idle animation won't loop

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

I have 2 animations on my weapon, an Attack animation and an Idle animation, here's the Animation component:

[image]

Of course, I need my idle animation to loop whilst the Attack animation isn't active, but when I play my game, my idle animation only plays **once**, but my attack animation plays fine, however I need my Idle animation to **loop**.

So I tried to change the '**Wrap Mode**' to '**Loop**':

[image]

Which loops my Idle animation perfectly, however it then loops my attack animation once I've attacked!

if it helps, here's my Melee Script:

```
if( Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
{
    // Attack animation
    Hatchet.GetComponent.<Animation>().Play("Attack");

    //Attack Function
    var hit : RaycastHit; 
    if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), hit))
    {
        Distance = hit.distance;
        if (Distance < maxDistance)
        {
            hit.transform.SendMessage("ApplyDamage", theDamage, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
        }
    }
}

if(Hatchet.GetComponent.<Animation>() == false)
{
    Hatchet.GetComponent.<Animation>().CrossFade("Idle");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be easier for you to use the Animator (Window -> Animator) it lets you set the order and cycle of animations in a GUI format.

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/animation/animator-controller

Answer (score 0):

play the idle animation when the attack is anim is finished

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationState-time.html

you are setting all the animation in loop mood not only the idle animation.